# Overflow bars created in Internet Explorer by CSS menu

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

> OK problem partially solved and the rest can be explained by the lack
> of support for IE
>
> I solved the x-axis with the inclusion of a 'overflow-x: hidden;' in
> the sidenav element The y axis remains with its scroll bar but IE is
> unsupported so it's not a big deal!  In fact
> https://www.w3schools.com/ example also has a y axis scroll bar in IE.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting scroll bars from my menu

It only happens in IE
I'm not a coder so I'm pulling my hair out a bit trying various things. I tried removing the home button on the right
Making the whole thing have a max width of 80% and less
Nothing seems to get rid of the flipping things

```html
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}


  
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1010;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
    
    
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
   width: 100%;
     text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
    
}



/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #740000;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
  left: 110px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 85px;
}

#main {
 transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

.menu{
 font-size: 30px;
  padding: 12px 0px 8px 3px;
    
}
    
.homebut{
    
    padding: 8px 15px 5px 12px;
        font-size: 30px;
    
        float:right;
}

    
    .homebut a {
  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #740000;
   display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  
}

    
 .column {
  float: left; 
  width:25%;
  padding:10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1020;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

    
.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
   padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.overlay a {
  
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  color: #000;
   display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #740000;
}

.overlay .closebtn2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.nolink {
font-size:25px;
font-weight: bold;
color:black;
padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
text-align:center;

}
.nolinkmain {
font-size:30px;
    font-weight: bold;
color:black;

    padding: 12px 0px 8px 0px;
text-align:center;

}

@media screen and (max-height:700px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    .overlay .closebtn2  {
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
  
@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay-content {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 15px;}
  .nolink {font-size: 15px;}
  .overlay-content {font-size: 20px;}
    .nolinkmain {font-size: 20px;}
    .menu {font-size: 25px;}
  .overlay .closebtn2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }

}
    
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Can nobody help?

Comment: Well, you _just_ added your code. No one was able to help since there wasn't any code before. You just have to wait a bit longer.

Comment: Also, there still isn't any HTML. Your styling is pretty useless without HTML. Make sure that when you run the code snippet, you can see the result and the problem.

Comment: I didn't put the code in initially because it's too big to fit in here (so there's only part of it there, even now) and it was readily available from the link.
There's no HTML because it's a server side include so it doesn't need any. It actually works fine on its own with no HTML anyway.

I solved the x-axis with the inclusion of a 'overflow-x: hidden;' in the sidenav element
The y axis remains with its scroll bar but IE is unsupported so it's not a big deal!  In fact https://www.w3schools.com/ example also has a y axis scroll bar in IE.